# Moving multiple scenes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm in the middle of making an JavaFX application and I have a question. My app has 6 scenes and in every one of them I copy and paste the same code responsible for moving a scene by mouse. This is my code:

```
//some class instance
public static double xOffset = 0;
public static double yOffset = 0;

scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            xOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
            yOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        }
    });
```

But im curious, is there any way to not copy/paste the same code in every controller for each scene? Can I just do something to write this code once and make any reference to it in every controller or something like this?

Comment: Why are those fields `public` and `static`?

Comment: I tried to stop repeating those declarations of variables in every class at least so that's why they are public and static. But it didn't work as I wanted to anyway.

Comment: I don't understand how it could work if you had the same offset for all the different scenes?

Comment: I know some things might be obvious for many of you, but I'm only a beginner in Java. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Fields should pretty much always be `private`. The only uses for static that are not at least moderately advanced are for constants and the `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course: just define a class to do that.

E.g.

```
public class SceneDragHandler {

    private double xOffset ;
    private double yOffset ;

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseDownHandler ;
    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseDragHandler ;

    private final Scene scene ;

    public SceneDragHandler(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene ;
        mouseDownHandler = e -> {
            xOffset = e.getSceneX();
            yOffset = e.getSceneY();
        };
        mouseDragHandler = e -> {
            scene.getWindow().setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            scene.getWindow().setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        };
        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mouseDownHandler);
        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, mouseDragHandler);
    }

    // may not need this:
    public void dispose() {
        scene.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mouseDownHandler);
        scene.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, mouseDragHandler);
    }

}
```

Then you can just do

```
new SceneDragHandler(scene);
```

whenever you need it.

I used `addEventHandler(...)` instead of `setOnMousePressed(...)` and `setOnMouseDragged(...)` to make it easier to remove the behavior, and also to allow you to register other behaviors on the scene independently of this.

I am assuming here

- making your `xOffset` and `yOffset` fields `public` and `static` was a mistake, and
- you want to drag the window containing the specified scene (if not, though anything else would seem weird, just create a field for the stage as well as the scene).

The `dispose()` method allows you to turn off the dragging behavior:

```
// turn on dragging behavior:
SceneDragHandler sceneDragHandler = new SceneDragHandler(scene);

// later....

// turn off dragging behavior:
sceneDragHandler.dispose();
```

If you don't think you need the `dispose()` functionality, then this just reduces to

```
public class SceneDragHandler {

    private double xOffset ;
    private double yOffset ;

    public SceneDragHandler(Scene scene) {

        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            xOffset = e.getSceneX();
            yOffset = e.getSceneY();
        });
        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e -> {
            scene.getWindow().setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            scene.getWindow().setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for help. It really makes code more clean and shorter :)